# Use Initialized Parameters from a servlet in my jsp not from doGet or doPost

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

How can I use my initialized parameters from my servlet in my jsp file without using doGet or doPost method?

Edit:
Since i wanna use only Java code in my Servlet my goal is to use initalized variables from my servlet in my jsp. While i load my jsp, a table should be filled with some data from an array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="object.*"%>
<%@page import="basic.Services"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shop | Weinhandel SW & DA</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<%
    Services dbService = new Services();    
%>
<body>
<div class="style3"></div><div class="style_2"><span class="style3"><a><strong></strong></a></span></div>
<div id="wrap">
    <!-- Start "HeaderBereich" -->
    <div id="topbar">
      <h1 id="sitename"><a>Weinhandlung SW & DA</a></h1>
      <div id="menus">
        <ul id="topmenu">
            <li>
                <h4><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></h4>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4><a href="shop.jsp">Shop</a></h4>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4><a href="Verwaltung.jsp">Mitarbeiterlogin</a></h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
    <!-- Beinhaltet nur das Headerbild -->
    </div>
    <!-- Ende "Headerbereich" -->
    <form method="post" action="WhServlet">
    <!--  Beginn Content Bereich -->
    <div id="content">
        <!--  Mainpage -->
        <div id="HeaderContent">
            <h2>Produkte</h2>
                <p>
                    Hier können Sie Ihren gewünschten Wein raussuchen und in den Warenkorb verschieben. Zur weiteren Hilfe
                    dienen Ihnen die Filter auf der rechten Seite.
                </p>
        </div>
        <div id="ShopMainpage">
            <p>
                <c:forEach items="${weinTable}" var="wein">
                <!-- Tabelle Wein -->               
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Jahrgang</th>
                        <th>Preis</th>
                        <th>Weingut</th>
                        <th>Typ</th>
                        <th>Art</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${wein.name}</td>
                        <td>${wein.jahrgang}</td>
                        <td>${wein.preis}</td>
                        <td>${wein.weingutBez}</td>
                        <td>${wein.weintypBez}</td>
                        <td>${wein.weinartBez}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </c:forEach>                
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar">

        </div>
        <!-- SidebarContent -->
        <div id="sidebarcontents">
            <a href="#">Warenkorb</a>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
                <!-- Art Filter -->
                <b>Art:</b>
                <p><select name="art" style="width: 100px">
                <option><%="" %></option><!-- leeren String als Startwert -->
                <c:forEach items="${artTable}" var="art">
                <option>${art.artBez}</option>
                </c:forEach>
                </select></p>
                <!-- Land Filter -->
                <b>Land:</b>
                <p><select name="land" style="width: 100px">
                <option><%="" %></option><!-- leeren String als Startwert -->
                <option></option>
                </select></p>
                <!-- Region Filter -->
                <b>Region:</b>
                <p><select name="region" style="width: 100px">
                <option><%="" %></option><!-- leeren String als Startwert -->
                <option></option>
                </select></p>
                <!-- Typ Filter -->
                <b>Typ:</b>
                <p><select name="typ" style="width: 100px">             
                <option><%="" %></option><!-- leeren String als Startwert -->
                <option></option>
                </select></p>
                <!-- Rebsorte Filter -->
                <b>Rebsorte:</b>
                <p><select name="rebsorte" style="width: 100px">                
                <option><%="" %></option><!-- leeren String als Startwert -->
                <option></option>
                </select></p>
                <!-- Weingut -->
                <b>Weingut:</b>
                <p><select name="weingut" style="width: 100px">             
                <option><%="" %></option><!-- leeren String als Startwert -->
                <option></option>
                </select></p>

            <!-- Filter Knopf -->
            <input type="submit" title="btnFilter" value="Filter ausführen"/>

            <br/>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Ende ContentBereich -->
    </form>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>Copyright &copy; 2014 | SW  DA Weinhandel</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see i have a table and comboboxes that are getting filled. When i press my submit button i will use the selected value from the combobox to create a statement and filter this table to show the correct dataset. So since ill only get values from my servlet over doPost or doGet, I´m not able to fill these comboboxes or table. I need a way to fill these my table and my comboboxes without pressing my submit button

Comment: not sure what you're asking for. You mean like default values for missing request parameters?

Comment: would you mind to post some code to illustrate what you're looking for?

Comment: @Leo I hope the above information helps

Comment: Thanks. As @hitham pointed. Scriptlets are a good option here

Comment: @Leo After i fill my tables i wanna be able to filter it. My SQL-Statement works perfectly fine, but after i press my button, it only shows the standard "wein table". Any ideas?^^

Comment: With jsf this would be trivial. For jsp, I think you can either use some Ajax library such as prototype.js or keep the state somehow (maybe the query parameters in a session or in hidden fields).

Comment: what's the code for the servlet?

Answer (score 0):

ServletClass.doPost

```
request.setAttribute("var", "TestString" );
```

JSP

```
<c:out value="${var}" />
```

Or just use Java code in scriptlets inside `<% %>`